# What is the most efficient way to implement GroupBy in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, grouping

I am trying to implement a `GroupBy` method with these parameters

```
function GroupBy(keySelector, elementSelector, comparer)
{
    // keySelector = function(e) { return e.ID }
    // elementSelector = function(e) { return e.Name }
    // comparer = { Equals: function(a,b) { return a==b }, GetHashCode:... }
}
```

However I don't know an efficient way to implement it.

[I created a jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/js-groupby-complex) with linq.js and a method I created which doesn't use a comparer and only work on flat types. ([Output test here](http://jsfiddle.net/BDQ4k/))

Other libraries such as underscore and Lo-Dash doesn't take a `comparer` parameter. So their implementations are irrelevant.

My key could be a class, so I need something to determine if `TKey` is the same in different instances.

So basically what I am trying to do is copy C# Linq `GroupBy` behavior [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Sample input:

```
var arrComplex =
[
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Bar" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Bar" }
];
```

Sample output (or something like this):

```
[
    {
       "Key": {"Value":10},
       "Elements":["Foo","Bar"]
    },
    {
        "Key": {"Value":20},
        "Elements":["Foo","Bar"]
    }
]
```

Any ideas on how to implement it?

#### Bounty

For the bounty I would like you take in consideration that:

- The key could be an object
- Two objects can be equal if some property is equal
- It should be as fast as or faster than existing solutions
- The result can be an array or object, doesn't matter as long as I can get elements grouped by a key

Well, I expect a complete answer.

Comment: Do you really need your own implementation? Can't you use `Underscore.js` or other library?

Comment: `Lo-Dash.js` is another alternative and it bills itself as faster and more efficient than `Underscore.js`

Comment: Both doesn't seem to have a `comparer` parameter.

Comment: @BrunoLM Why do you need `comparer`? What happens if `comparer` returns 'equality' for two elements with different keys? What key will be used for this group?

Comment: I need a comparer to group by a complex type. My `Key` could be a class.

Comment: You want the "Most efficient" way - how large are the data sets you're working on? I'd `.reduce` here most likely but that's not the most efficient, the most efficient is a Map and a for loop.

Comment: Could you add an example where you would need the comparer? And the expected output?

Comment: Thanks, the question is much more understandable now :) Since the keys are created using literals, i suppose you want a to do a test for deep equality on the keys, not a reference check, is that correct?

Comment: The keys could be anything. I would determine the equality by using a method `Equals` (ex: `function(a,b){return a.N.Value == b.N.Value;}`) and maybe a `GetHashCode` (ex: `function(a) { return a.N.Value; }`).

Comment: love the question. gave me something to do today :)

Comment: @loushou I am really glad to hear that there is still people that code for fun, like me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement this way:

I need to get the hashcode from objects.

```
Object.prototype.GetHashCode = function () {
    var s = this instanceof Object ? stringify(this) : this.toString();

    var hash = 0;
    if (s.length === 0) return hash;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + s.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return hash;
};
Number.prototype.GetHashCode = function () { return this.valueOf(); };
```

As `JSON.stringify` will fail at circular references, I created another method to stringify it in a way I can get the most of an object as a string and compute the hashcode over it, as follows:

```
function isPlainObject(obj)
{
    if ((typeof (obj) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || (obj instanceof Window))
        || (obj.constructor && !({}).hasOwnProperty.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf"))
    )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
function stringify(obj, s)
{
    s = s || "";

    for (var i in obj)
    {
        var o = obj[i];

        if (o && (o instanceof Array || isPlainObject(o)))
        {
            s += i + ":" + JSON.stringify(o);
        }
        else if (o && typeof o === "object")
        {
            s += i + ":" + "$ref#" + o;
        }
        else
        {
            s += i + ":" + o;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

There isn't much impact on performance. For large object it is the same and for small objects it loses, but is still pretty fast and safe. [Performance test here](http://jsperf.com/json-stringify/2).

```
Name                         op/s
---------------------------------
JSON.stringify large           62
stringify      large           62
JSON.stringify small    1,690,183
stringify      small    1,062,452
```

My GroupBy method

```
function GroupBy(a, keySelector, elementSelector, comparer)
{
    // set default values for opitinal parameters
    elementSelector = elementSelector || function(e) { return e; };
    comparer = comparer ||
        {
            Equals: function(a,b) { return a==b },
            GetHashCode: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
        };

    var key, hashKey, reHashKey;

    // keep groups separated by hash
    var hashs = {};
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // in case of same hash, but Equals returns false
        reHashKey = undefined;

        // grabs the key
        key = keySelector(a[i]);
        // grabs the hashcode
        hashKey = comparer.GetHashCode(key);

        // if a hash exists in the list
        // compare values with Equals
        // in case it return false, generate a unique hash
        if (typeof hashs[hashKey] !== "undefined")
            reHashKey = comparer.Equals(key, hashs[hashKey].Key) ? hashKey : hashKey + " " + i;

        // if a new hash has been generated, update
        if (typeof reHashKey !== "undefined" && reHashKey !== hashKey)
            hashKey = reHashKey;

        // get/create a new group and add the current element to the list
        hashs[hashKey] = hashs[hashKey] || { Key: key, Elements: [] };
        hashs[hashKey].Elements.push(a[i]);
    }

    return hashs;
}
```

To test

```
var arrComplex =
[
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 10 }, Name: "Bar" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Foo" },
    { N: { Value: 20 }, Name: "Bar" }
];
//

var x = GroupBy(arrComplex
        , function(e) { return e.N; }
        , function(e) { return e.Name; }
        , {
              Equals: function(a,b) { return a.Value == b.Value },
              GetHashCode: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
          }
);
//

console.log(x);
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Bup/2/), now with Jedi.

But, [accordingly to my tests](http://jsperf.com/js-groupby-complex), my implementation of `GroupBy` is slower than linq.js's `GroupBy`. It is only faster when I convert `ToArray()`. Maybe linq.js only really executes when I convert to array, that's why the difference, I am not sure on this part.

Test results

```
Name                         op/s
---------------------------------
GroupBy                   163,261
GroupByToArray            152,382
linq.js groupBy           243,547
linq.js groupBy toArray    26,309
```

Answer (score 5):

I used your jsperf as a reference, for some of the finer points of script. I really, really liked your 'hash' code, so I totally stole it. Mine uses a different method to generate the string used to make the hash, which seems to be a little faster, which increases the performance, according to the 'browserscope' charts. I include in my test a 'too much recursion' proof of concept to show that it has recursion protection, like JSON.stringify and .toSource().

[My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTC4g/) shows that the code returns the format you need. [My jsperf](http://jsperf.com/group-by-complex-fast) seems to indicate that it outperforms the posted solution. I also included the linq.js solution, but it performs pretty bad in FireFox for me. It works comparably in Safari, Chrome, an IE, but not faster than mine, except in IE. I even tried it on my phone, and still I have the same performance difference. I have personally tested it in the latest versions of all browsers in a side-by-side to the posted solution, and mine out performs by around 40% across each of them. What are everyone's thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
var arr = [
  { N: 10, Name: "Foo" },
  { N: 10, Name: "Bar" },
  { N: 20, Name: "Foo" },
  { N: 20, Name: "Bar" }
];

var poc = { name:'blah', obj:{} };
poc.obj = poc;
var arrComplex = [
  { N: { Value: 10, TooMuchRecursionProofPOC:poc }, Name: "Foo" },
  { N: { Value: 10, TooMuchRecursionProofPOC:poc }, Name: "Bar" },
  { N: { Value: 20, TooMuchRecursionProofPOC:poc }, Name: "Foo" },
  { N: { Value: 20, TooMuchRecursionProofPOC:poc }, Name: "Bar" }
];

var eArr = Enumerable.From(arr);
var eArrComplex = Enumerable.From(arrComplex);

function setup_hashers() {
  // recursion protection idea
  var rp = '_rp'+(Math.random()*10000000);

  function tstr() {
    var out = '', i = '';
    if (this[rp]) { this[rp] = undefined; return out; }
    for (i in this)
      if (i != rp && this.hasOwnProperty(i))
        out += this[i] instanceof Object
          ? ((this[rp] = true) && this[i] != this && !this[i][rp] ? tstr.call(this[i]) : '')
          : (this[i].toString || tstr).call(this[i]);
    return out;
  };

  Number.prototype.GetHashCode = function() {
    return this.valueOf();
  };

  Object.prototype.GetHashCode = function() {
    var s = (this instanceof Object ? tstr : this.toString || tstr).call(this),
      h = 0;
    if (s.length)
      for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        h = ((h << 5) - h) + s.charCodeAt(i);

    return h;
  };
}

function group_by(a, keyFunc, valFunc, comp, as_array) {
  if (!a.length) return as_array ? [] : {};

  var keyFunc = keyFunc || function (e) { return e; },
      valFunc = valFunc || function (e) { return e; };
  var comp = comp || {
      Equals: function (a, b) { return a == b; },
      Hash: function (e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
  };


  var hashs = {}, key = '', hash = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    key = keyFunc(a[i]);
    hash = comp.Hash(key);
    if (typeof hashs[hash] != 'undefined')
      hash = comp.Equals(key, hashs[hash].Key)
        ? hash
        : hash + '-' + i;
    hashs[hash] = hashs[hash] || { Key: key, Elements: [] };
    hashs[hash].Elements.push(valFunc(a[i]));
  }

  if (as_array) {
    var out = [], j = '', keys = Object.keys(hashs);
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++)
      out.push(hashs[keys[j]]);
    return out;
  }

  return hashs;
};

function group_by_control(a, keyFunc, valFunc) {
  if (!a.length) return as_array ? [] : {};

  var keyFunc = keyFunc || function (e) { return e; },
      valFunc = valFunc || function (e) { return e; };

  var hashs = {}, key = '', hash = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    key = keyFunc(a[i]);
    hashs[key] = hashs[key] || { Key: key, Elements: [] };
    hashs[key].Elements.push(valFunc(a[i]));
  }

  var out = [], j = '', keys = Object.keys(hashs);
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++)
  out.push(hashs[keys[j]]);
  return out;
};

setup_hashers();

console.log(group_by_control(
  arr,
  function(e) { return e.N },
  function(e) { return e.Name }
));

console.log(group_by(
  arrComplex, function(e) { return e.N; },
  function(e) { return e.Name; },
  {
    Equals: function(a, b) { return a.Value == b.Value },
    Hash: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
  }
));

console.log(group_by(
  arrComplex, function(e) { return e.N; },
  function(e) { return e.Name; },
  {
    Equals: function(a, b) { return a.Value == b.Value },
    Hash: function(e) { return e.GetHashCode(); }
  },
  true
));
```

Answer (score 0):

My simplest implementation using `Map`:

```
function groupByObjectKey(array, callback) {
    const groups = new Map();

    array.forEach(item => {
        const key = callback(item);

        if (!groups.has(key)) {
            groups.set(key, []);
        }

        groups.get(key).push(item);
    });

    return Object.fromEntries(groups.entries());
}
```