# array of arrays comparision jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array which holds an arrays of data and values. I am running in to a problem of figuring out the unique array based on those data I have.

```
ex:
var x =[[1,2,3,abc],[3,4,5,xyz],[5,6,7,abc]];
I wanted:

var y =[[6,8,10,abc],[3,4,5,xyz]];
```

so I had this feeling to loop through the first array to check the possible match of the text and add the corresponding value and return the integrated array.

need some help to understand these logic.

appreciated any help.

Comment: I think you want to [compare arrays to arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/2033671)

Comment: Do you mean [merging arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)?

Comment: I don't know how to get started, I want to compare the string part on each array with another array, if match found I want to combine the number value of those matched items and keep the string part as one array. ex:
var x =[[1,2,3,abc],[3,4,5,xyz],[5,6,7,abc],[7,8,9,abc]];
I wanted:
to compare in between x arrays and return
var y =[[13,16,19,abc],[3,4,5,xyz]];

Comment: What is the data's origin?

Comment: these are the json data and I have captured it in an array of Arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvFt5/).

[GroupBy reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20633550/340760)

```
function GroupBy(a, keySelector, elementSelector)
{
    elementSelector = elementSelector || function(e) { return e; };

    var key;
    var hashs = {};
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i)
    {
        key = keySelector(a[i]);
        hashs[key] = hashs[key] || []
        hashs[key].push(a[i]);
    }

    return hashs;
}
```

With this method I can group arrays by a centain key:

```
var x =[[1,2,3,"abc"],[3,4,5,"xyz"],[5,6,7,"abc"]];

var grouped = GroupBy(x, function(k) { return k[k.length-1]; });
```

I am grouping by the last element of each array inside the big array. Then I accumulate the values and remove the ones I already computed:

```
for (var i in grouped)
{
    var arr = grouped[i];
    for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; )
    {
        for (var p = 0; p < arr[j].length - 1; ++p)
        {
            arr[0][p] += arr[j][p];
        }
        arr.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
```

The result is

```
console.log(grouped);
```

[image: result]